# SELECT Showing me a list with the name of the column and not the data inside

Tags: mysql, sql

I have quite a strange problem, I'm very new to SQL and I was doing a free course in SQL

I'm actually learning the "SELECT" command.

So, I create my database, create some table, put some data in it with the "INSERT INTO" command

And now I want to select some data in it, but I have a strange bug (not an error) when i do

```
SELECT * FROM aliment;
```

everything work like it's supposed to do, but when I do

```
SELECT 'nom','calories' FROM aliment;
```

Something strange happens.

Instead have a list of all the specific data i'm looking to get i just get a list with all the data replaced by the name of the columns.

Here 2 screen to show you what's happens:

[image: What I'm looking to get]

[[image: What's I'm getting instead...][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjfsK.png)

I know one it's from the terminal(and yes it's not mine but from a video) and mine is from the software, but it's still had to work no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your SQL. Use backticks (on the same key as `~` on a US keyboard) around your column names, not `'`. Using a single quote (an apostrophe) makes it a literal value, not a column name.

```
SELECT `nom`,`calories`FROM aliment;
```